# How to use a single supply with an opamp to create a DC amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, gain

I have a single positive power supply, and I want to amplify a DC input signal.  All sources I have seen decouple the input voltage with a capacitor because the input voltage is biased at VCC/2, however this would filter out the DC voltage that I want to amplify.  How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the LTC2050 - http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/2050fc.pdf or investigate chopper stabilised amps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input signal ranges from 0V (or less) to some positive value then you should generate a negative supply. This will then set the OPAMP's power rails at suitable voltages for bipolar input and output operation. You can find chips that do this.

If the input voltage is purely positive in nature (and can get close to 0V) then use an OPAMP that is "rail-to-rail" on inputs and outputs.

If your input signal is from (say) +2V to some higher voltage then virtually any op-amp will do but check the data sheet.